# On the American usage of the words Congressman, Representative and Senator

Tags: etymology, politics

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/congressman):

> ### congressman
>
> a member of a congress
> *especially* : a member of the U.S. House of Representatives
>
> Examples of congressman in a Sentence:
> a former congressman who is now a senator

From [BallotPedia](https://ballotpedia.org/List_of_current_members_of_the_U.S._Congress):

> ### U.S. Senate
>
> #### Leadership and partisan balance
>
> U.S. Senate leadership
>
> | Position | Representative | Party |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | President of the Senate | Kamala Harris | Democratic |
> | **Senate Majority Leadership** |  |  |
> | President pro tempore | Patrick Leahy | Democratic |
> | Senate Majority Leader | Chuck Schumer | Democratic |
> | Senate Majority Whip | Dick Durbin | Democratic |
> | **Senate Minority Leadership** |  |  |
> | Senate Minority Leader | Mitch McConnell | Republican |
> | Senate Minority Whip | John Thune | Republican |

Now then.

It seems pretty obvious to me how this should work. Senators work in the Senate, representatives work in the House of Representatives, and as the two houses make up the Congress, they are all congressmen. And yet, inexplicably, it seems that most people won't live by that simple code.

Or is it really inexplicable? In other words, can someone offer some sort of explanation of how this obvious pairing-up has failed to gain a very widespread acceptance?

**Some reactions to the March 23 answer by phoog:**

I agree that avoidance of all ambiguity would be difficult here, as it often is in life; and that there's something strange about using the word "representative," which seems like the most general term, for members of one chamber but not the other. I also assume that all of these words for political offices had meanings before the Constitution was adopted. But I would expect that the senses that the Founding Fathers attached to them would be the most natural ones now. Thus, it seems unsurprising to me that I don't hear the President or Vice President of the United States ever called "representatives," tho they are representatives in way. Nobody ever refers to the Speaker of the House of Representatives as "the president of the House of Representatives." It would not seem natural now to use words quite that broadly, as if they were all up for grabs. I suppose that the members of the Continental Congress were chosen by state legislatures, the way Senators were chosen under the original constitution; so perhaps Congress would have seemed an appropriate word for the Senate. But that would be pretty confusing. It seems to me that the very ambiguity that you point to would lead people to defer to the Constitution's use of these words. Section 2, about the House of Representatives, refers to members as "representatives." Section 3, about the Senate, refers to members as "senators." The Constitution does not use the term "congressmen" at all. So if, as you say, some people have this anxiety about words ending m-e-n, these people would happy (or relatively so) in a world that speaks as I proposed, of representatives and senators usually, and of congressmen (or members of Congress) rarely, for members of either chamber, the sense that you say is rarely needed.

In other words, your answer seems to be that the usages that I object to are actually better because less ambiguous or less cumbersome. I don't see how that's true. I also realize that there's no helping it if people won't talk as I want them to talk, and perhaps all we can do is try to imagine their perspective, rather calling them names to announce our own moral superiority. But I wonder if there's a more historical explanation about the trajectory of these words in American history that's escaping us both.

Answer (score 6):

> Or is it really inexplicable? In other words, can someone offer some sort of explanation of how this obvious pairing-up has failed to gain a very widespread acceptance?

"Representative" is ambiguous.  It could refer to a representative in a completely different context, such as someone who attends a meeting on behalf of a company or other group.  In spoken language, without the benefit of capitalization, it could also refer to senators, because, after all, senators also represent their states in congress.  So to be fully unambiguous, you have to say "member of the House of Representatives."  You can't even say "member of the House," because the senate is also a house of congress.

This is cumbersome.  Accordingly, the convention was adopted that "congressman" and "congresswoman" are short for "member of the House of Representatives," because members of the senate already have a short one-word designation, namely "senator."  This is reflected in the given definition starting at "especially."

When it is necessary to refer to members of both houses collectively (or generally, without regard to which house they belong to), we therefore need something other than "congressman" and "congresswoman."  The more cumbersome "member of congress" typically serves here.  Because this designation is required less frequently, it's more efficient to use "congressman" for members of the house of representatives instead of for members of both houses.  It also has the advantage of being gender neutral.

In recent decades, the concern for gender-neutral language has put more than a little negative pressure on "congressman" and "congresswoman," so there has been some shifting, and phrases like "congressional representative" seem to be more common.

It's not strictly logical, but language use often abandons logical rigor for the sake of efficiency.

Comment: I think there's also a sense that senators are more senior than congresspeople, and therefore deserve a more specific title. Senators often stay in their job for a very long time, there are fewer of them, and it's commoner to go from house of representatives to senate than vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please see my modifications to my question.